# Restarting Node.js with Forever

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, capistrano

I have a Capistrano recipe for deploying a Node.js application

```
 task :start, :roles => :app do
   run "cd #{current_path} && NODE_ENV=#{node_env} forever start socket-server.js"
 end

 task :stop, :roles => :app do
   run "cd #{current_path} && NODE_ENV=#{node_env} forever stop socket-server.js"
 end

 task :restart, :roles => :app do
   run "cd #{current_path} && NODE_ENV=#{node_env} forever restart socket-server.js"
 end
```

The problem is the "restart" task, there should be a check if the server is already running.

Because restarting a not running server trough forever doesn't work, I need to run it first when it is not running. But how I can do the check ?

Answer (score 0):

Make your restart task call the stop and start tasks.

```
task :restart do
  stop
  sleep 5
  start
end
```